How to use generator expressions in CMake for a standard IF-ELSE statement during configuration stage?
I am new to CMake and multi generators, in my case Visual Studio 16 2019.
On Linux I would use Unix Makefile, set CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE and then check that throughout my CMakeLists.txt using various if-else statements to determine what actions to undertake based on the type.
From what I understand and have seen myself CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is simply ignored by multi generators.
I have seen various examples such as
target_link_libraries(MyApp PRIVATE
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:CheckedAlgo>
    $<$<NOT:$<CONFIG:Debug>>:FastAlgo>
)

where branching based on build type is done inline using various generator expressions. However, I am unable to find a single if(...) ... else() ... endif() out there using such expressions other than as an inline option (e.g. $<IF:>).
Currently have a CI pipeline that produces both debug and release builds of various dependencies I am using. I use FetchContent to retrieve those during the configuration step (the artifacts include header files, library binaries etc. all of which are needed either during the build step or runtime).
How would I branch out using generator expressions during the configuration stage in my CMakeLists.txt, thus making it possible to download and/or copy various files for the specific type of build?
Example:
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
  ...
else()
  ...
endif()

Currently I do big time cheating, namely in my CMakeLists.txt or via command line argument I set CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES to a single type (e.g.Debug) and then check (STREQUAL) the value in a similar ways as to when I am using CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.
This allows me to limit the build configurations to a single one so
cmake --build <build-dir> --target ALL_BUILD

which normally goes for Release, is automatically executing a Debug build. It works but since I haven't seen people do it I am assuming it is indeed cheating.


How would I branch out using generator expressions during the configuration stage in my CMakeLists.txt, thus making it possible to download and/or copy various files for the specific type of build?

You cannot do this. And this simply has no sense.
The main workflow of multiconfiguration generators (for which generator expressions have been introduced) is

Configure once.
Build for one build type (e.g. Debug).
Build for another build type (e.g. Release).

That is, after a single configuration you should have files downloaded for all build types which your project supports.
You may choose to defer downloading of files, which are specific for a build type, until building, when build type becomes known. For that you could use add_custom_command and/or add_custom_target, which COMMAND is executed during the build. Or you could use ExternalProject, which steps are executed on the build stage too.


Currently I do big time cheating, namely in my CMakeLists.txt or via command line argument I set CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES to a single type (e.g. Debug) and then check (STREQUAL) the value in a similar ways as to when I am using CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.

Yes, you could follow that way if you find that supporting single configuration pass for multiple build types is too difficult or unnecessary for your case.
From my understanding, you could even use CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE variable in that case: CMake doesn't use that variable in case of multiconfiguration generators, so you are free to use it for your own purposes. In that case your CMake code will be the same for both single- and multi-configuration generators (except from setting CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES in the latter case).

The problem is that I need those files (the Debug ones) also for the development. Headers that I download are then included using target_include_directories() and used for writing new features in the existing code base. ExternalProject does not help here exactly because it is executed during the build stage.

So, just download those files during the configuration.

I found this. I can iterate through all configuration types and do different things respectively.

I cannot just download files since they will overwrite each other, which may or may not be what is desired (it depends e.g. on whether you have Debug- vs. Release-specific headers, libs, config files etc.).

Download files needed for Debug into the Debug/ subdirectory, and download files needed for Release into Release/ subdirectory. When specify sources in add_executable or include directories in target_include_directories use $<CONFIG> generator expression for a subdirectory part.

Yes, but my current CI creates both the Debug and Release, each in their respective artifacts subdir. One can create branch-per-build-type so that the pipeline is different and the artifacts are also different, but this requires more effort on the CI side.

So your CI configures the project once per each build type, thus utilizing only a single build type per configuration. Am I correctly understand your case? So you (as a project developer) could limit usage of your project only to a single type per configuration, as I described in the second part of my post. If you want to support "true" multiconfiguration generation aside CI, then you could introduce some configuration option, which could be set by CI for perform "reduced" configuration, suitable only for a single build type.

The major problem (which I am facing now after implementing download for every configuration type) is the size of the download during an initial setup. I need - among other things - libtorch, where just the CUDA debug version is several gigabytes. Using the foreach() from the post I linked I can actually limit what is downloaded and even provide more streamlined procedures for handling dependencies. Your first statement ("You can't. It makes no sense") is thus incorrect. There are multiple possibilities to handle the configuration step.

In the end it is the configuration step that can provide (as you have mentioned in your comment) a limiter on the possible build types and even introduce new ones as described here.

Your question (which I cited in my answer) is about limiting a downloads for single type of build. How iteration over several build types and downloading files for every of them is a solution for that problem? Also, unless your project is used as a subproject, you are perfectly aware which build types you are selecting to support. That is, you absolutely not "limiting" your downloads: you download files for all build types you want to support.

BTW, instead of iterating over CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES you could check inclusion of a specific build type into that list: if(Debug IN_LIST CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES) and base on this check when decide to include debug files.
